# How to access static variable inside instance method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

So i am using a GenericAPIView when my post method is hit function gets called and perform certain action like creating and completing some objects in my class. so i am using a static method here but in exception i am not being able to refer to variable named *var* used in static method to use in my post method exception

```
class MyApiView(GenericAPIView):

    @staticmethod
    def my_custom_method(arg):
        if condition1 and condition2:
           var = Class1(arg=arg)
           var.create()
        
           var = Class2(arg=arg)
           var.complete()
         
        if condition4 or condition3:
           var = Class3(arg=arg)
           var.create()
        
     def post(self, request):
         try:
            my_cust_method(arg)
         except Exception:
            logger.error(f"{var.__class__}", exc_info=True)
```

**Unresolved reference var**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `var` is a local variable. It is local to your `my_custom_method` static method. If you would like to access it from other methods then you will need to declare it as a class (static) variable.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
class MyApiView(GenericAPIView):

    var = None

    @staticmethod
    def my_custom_method(arg):
        if condition1 and condition2:
           MyApiView.var = Class1(arg=arg)
           MyApiView.var.create()
        
           MyApiView.var = Class2(arg=arg)
           MyApiView.var.complete()
         
        if condition4 or condition3:
           MyApiView.var = Class3(arg=arg)
           MyApiView.var.create()
        
     def post(self, request):
         try:
            my_cust_method(arg)
         except Exception:
            if MyApiView.var == None:
                logger.error(f"var not initialised", exc_info=True)
            else:
                logger.error(f"{MyApiView.var.__class__}", exc_info=True)
```